# how many connection can you have in ActiveRecord connection pool?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

My use case is a multi-tenant Rails app. Each app uses a different database server, and the connections are managed through the [AR connection pool](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html). Currently it's doing well with 10 connections, but I'm curious if there is an upper limit to this resource.

Answer (score 0):

The upper limit is your database upper limit, not Rails or ActiveRecord limits.